# No styles applied using Play! 2.0 PDF module

Tags: java, css, pdf, playframework

I recently installed the [PDF module for Play! 2.0](https://github.com/joergviola/play20-pdf) and was able to wire it up to render a PDF without much difficulty. However, it looks like it's not loading my stylesheet, since no styles get applied to the PDF.

I've tried referencing my stylesheet using the classpath:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/pdf.css" media="screen" />
```

I've also tried referencing it using `@routes`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/pdf.css")" media="screen" />
```

In an attempt to keep it simple, I've included only one style in my stylesheet:

```
td {
    color: blue;
}
```

If I render as HTML, the text in my table is blue, but if I render as PDF, it's all black.

If this is a known issue, I don't see it anywhere. I'm under the impression this should work, so it seems like I must be missing something or doing something wrong. Can anyone help?

I've also [reported the issue here](https://github.com/joergviola/play20-pdf/issues/4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the only issue, but I wrote about one issue in my book when I wrote about the PDF module for play 1.x.

The CSS you are using (and the default for Play when first generated) is to use `media="screen"`. A PDF is classified as print. You therefore need to set media="print".

```
media="print"
```

So it would be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/pdf.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I considered trying that, but saw that the example on the github page was using `media="screen"` so I assumed  it was okay. I'll give it a shot. Much appreciated.