# Starting a process from a Java application

Tags: java, playframework, wkhtmltopdf

I know more or less how to do this, but I think I'm getting burned by the complexity of this command due to inexperience.

I'm trying to feed some raw html into `wkhtmltopdf`. I can do this from the command line like this:

```
echo "<p>Hello</p>" | wkhtmltopdf - ~/somePdf.pdf
```

That works fine, but how do I do this from a Java app? Here's a couple things I've tried:

```
String[] cmd = { "echo", html.body(), "|", "wkhtmltopdf", "-", "/home/sam/yourPdf.pdf" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

OR

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo " + html.body() + " | wkhtmltopdf - /home/sam/yourPdf.pdf");
```

Neither one of these produces a file in my home folder.

I've read that `wkhtmltopdf` will output to STDERR, but I'm not sure how to view that from Eclipse. I was told it should be available in my Console view, but I don't see anything there.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**

The accepted answer will work for `wkhtmltopdf`, but for anyone else using the Play! framework who finds this post, [there is a Play! module](https://github.com/joergviola/play20-pdf) that generates a PDF based on a scala template. It works really well, but [don't forget to set `media="print"` in your stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998602/no-styles-applied-using-play-2-0-pdf-module) :)

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: That is good information, but unfortunately not very helpful to me :) The `waitFor()` method concludes almost instantly and returns 0.

Comment: @Samo Read the other pages, it describes your situation exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, because you are running two commands and you create a pipe. Neither the `Runtime.exec()` nor the `ProcessBuilder.command()` methods are made for this. The easiest way to still achieve something akin to this from Java is to put all that stuff into a shell script and call that script with `Runtime.exec()` .

EDIT:
You can also skip the shell script and call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "bash", "-c", "\"echo \"<p>Hello</p>\ | wkhtmltopdf - ~/somePdf.pdf\""} );
```

That save you writing the shell script, but you may have to fiddle with the quotes a little to get it right.

Comment: Put commas between your array elements and give the last array element an end quote and you'll have yourself a green tick.

Comment: Wow, syntax checking :) I wonder how these got lost when I wrote this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to output your error stream to your console:

```
try{
    Runtime runTime= Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process= runTime.exec("echo " + html.body() + " | wkhtmltopdf - /home/sam/yourPdf.pdf");

    BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        System.err.println(line);
    }
}catch(Exception exe){
    exe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that this is specific to getting what is printed to your error stream. I hope this helps to get you started